# wxWidgets MinGW Build Error

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw, wxwidgets

Friends!

I Try Build wxWidgets with MinGW and Show This Error:

`F:\CPP\DevTools\wxWidgets-3.1.0\build\msw>mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc SHARED=1 UNICODE=1 BUILD=release
if not exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\mswu mkdir ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\mswu
gcc -c -o gcc_mswudll\wxtiff_tif_win32.o -O2 -mthreads  -DHAVE_W32API_H -DNDEBUG -I..\..\src\zlib -I..\..\src\jpeg -I..\..\src\tiff\libtiff   -MTgcc_mswudll\wxtiff_tif_win32.o -MFgcc_mswudll\wxtiff_tif_win32.o.d -MD -MP ../../src/tiff/libtiff/tif_win32.c
In file included from ../../src/tiff/libtiff/tiffio.h:257:0,
                  from ../../src/tiff/libtiff/tiffiop.h:59,
                  from ../../src/tiff/libtiff/tif_win32.c:30:
f:\cpp\devtools\mingw\include\stdio.h:345:12: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '__mingw__snprintf'  extern int __mingw_stdio_redirect__(snprintf)(char*, size_t, const char*, ...);
makefile.gcc:6018: recipe for target 'gcc_mswudll\wxtiff_tif_win32.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [gcc_mswudll\wxtiff_tif_win32.o] Error 1`

What i do?

Comment: What version/distribution of MinGW do you use? I.e. where does the file `f:\cpp\devtools\mingw\include\stdio.h` come from, exactly?

Comment: just download the binaries if you dont have to compile it for some reason. However, the compilation should work unless you are using an old version of gcc.

Comment: F:\CPP\DevTools\MinGW\include\stdio.h

Comment: MinGW-Get Version 0.6.2-beta-20131004-1

Comment: mingw32-gcc-g++ Version 6.3.0-1

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the (still unresolved) issue with MinGW32 GCC 6.3 I reported on wxTrac couple of months ago: 
https://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/17936

Until the issue is resolved either on wxWidgets or MinGW32 side, you will not be able to build wxWidgets with that particular MinGW32 version. Unless you are willing to use the workaround described in the page linked above (which I would not recommend), you need to use a different MinGW32 version or a different compiler toolchain. The previous MinGW32 version using GCC 5.3 works as expected with wxWidgets.